# AJAX Issue of ModSecurity Action

Tags: javascript, ajax

The Below URL is throwing an error of "Modsecurity forbidden status code: 403". The below URL is getting returned from AJAX

https://simple.com/forms/test/listrecord.php?page=2&fp=0&sql_where=fullname like ? and active = ?&params='%ABCDE%'|1&element_id=hello

If I removed %% from ABCDE like below URL then it is working fine.

The Below URL is throwing an error of Modsecurity forbidden

https://simple.com/forms/test/listrecord.php?page=2&fp=0&sql_where=fullname like ? and active = ?&params='ABCDE'|1&element_id=hello

Comment: It would be fine to see the part of your error.log for relevant request above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this implementation: I would like to suggest few things:

1. remove '%' before sending to AJAX and replace it with character 'like--' or something else
2. Before it hit the Database, again replace the 'like--' back to '%'
3. In this way you apply the solution

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have will implement it.